# Error below TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this small problem where I get the Cannot read properties of undefined error, but I don't know where the issue is. Can someone help me with this one?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] }, { partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]})
const { prefix, token } = require ('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');


client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

var serverID  = '832712939457871882';
var channelID = '832712940562022480';
var messageID = '833299637996748800';
var categoryID= '833295884992643102';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("[+] bot is up!")

    //Ticket module
    client.guilds.cache.get(serverID) //serverID
    .channels.cache.get(channelID) //channelID
    .messages.fetch(messageID).then(msg => msg.react('️')) //messageID
});
```

**ERROR**

```
C:\Users\MIG TECNICA\Desktop\dbotrp\index.js:35
    .channels.cache.get(channelID) //channelID
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
```

Comment: Issue is that `client.guilds.cache.get(serverID)` is `undefined`.

Comment: how to solve???

Answer (score 0):

Use `client.guilds.fetch(‘guild id here’).channels.cache.find(c => c.id === ‘channel id here’).messages.fetch(‘message id here’).then(msg => { msg.react(‘emoji here’); });`